# PhPmailer не приходят данные из полей output

Tags: php, form, phpmailer

Всем привет.

Есть форма: 7 полей для ввода. 4 Input и 3 output.
На почту приходят значения только из полей input. Атрибуты name прописаны везде и соответствуют друг другу.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело.

Спасибо

```
html

<form class="form-calculator" action="https://mysite.ru/mail.php" method="POST">
            <div class="range-container">
                <div class="cameras-container"> 
                    <p class="heading">Количество желаемых камер, (шт.)</p>
                    <div class="cam-field-container">
                        <input class="input-field camera-count" name="camera-count" type="range" min="1" max="16" value="1">
                        <output class="output-camera">1</output>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="archive-container">
                    <p class="heading">Размер желаемого архива, (дн.)</p>
                    <div class="arch-field-container">
                        <input class="input-field archive-count" name="archive-count" type="range" min="0" max="180" value="0">
                        <output class="output-archive">0</output>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="equip-price-container">
                <p class="heading">Минимальная стоимость оборудования (бюджетный вариант):</p>
                <output class="output-field equipprices-field" name="camera-cost">0 руб.</output>
            </div>
            <div class="work-price-container">
                <p class="heading">Стоимость работ:</p>
                <output class="output-field workprice-field" name="archive-cost">0 руб.</output>
            </div>
            <div class="contacts-container">
                <p class="heading contacts-heading">Вы можете получить подробное коммерческое предложение по
                    произведенному Вами расчету. Для этого укажите вашу почту, номер телефона и наш специалист свяжется
                    с Вами:
                </p>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input class="contact-input js_input _email" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail*:">
                    <input class="contact-input js_input _phone" type="text" name="phone-number" id="number" placeholder="Ваш номер*:">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="total-price-container">
                <p class="heading">ИТОГО СТОИМОСТЬ СИСТЕМЫ ВИДЕОНАБЛЮДЕНИЯ ПОД КЛЮЧ:</p>
                <output class="output-field totalprice-field" name="total-cost">0 руб.</output>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-btn-container">
                <input class="form-submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit-btn" id="submit-btn" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
                <div class="btn-shadow"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox-container">
                <input class="agreement-checkbox _checkbox" type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="agreement" checked>
                <label class="agreement-label" for="agreement"><span>Нажимая на кнопку "ОТПРАВИТЬ" Вы соглашаетесь на обработку
                персональных данных в соответствии с <a class="agreement-link" href="">политикой конфиденциальности</a></span></label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

```
css

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

.main-container {
    max-width: 700px;
    font-family: Inter;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.note-text {
    color: #73818c;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.calculator-form {
    font-family: Inter;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.equip-price-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.work-price-container {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contacts-container {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.contacts-heading {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.350);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact-input {
    flex-basis: 45%;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.350);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: box-shadow .3s ease 0s;
}

.contact-input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #11578d;
}

.contact-input::placeholder {
    color: #73818c;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-field {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input-field::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #1d8fe8;
    border: 1px solid #1d8fe8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input-field::-moz-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #1d8fe8;
    border: 1px solid #1d8fe8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input-field::-ms-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #1d8fe8;
    border: 1px solid #1d8fe8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.output-field {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #73818c;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cam-field-container,
.arch-field-container {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.350);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: box-shadow .3s ease 0s;
}

.cam-field-container:hover,
.arch-field-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #11578d;
}

.output-camera,
.output-archive {
    width: 20px;
    color: #73818c;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.total-price-container {
    height: 100px;
}

.submit-btn-container {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-submit-btn {
    padding: 16px 32px;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow .3s ease 0s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-submit-btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #11578d;
}

.form-submit-btn:active {
    box-shadow: inset 1px -2px 10px 1px #1a84d454, 0 3px 10px #11578d;
}

.checkbox-container {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: box-shadow .2s ease 0s;
}

.warning-message {
    padding: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.warning-range {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.650);
}

._error {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px red;
}

.agreement-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.agreement-checkbox:checked + .agreement-label::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.agreement-label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 140%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.agreement-label::before {
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '';
    align-self: flex-start;
    flex: 0 0 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.agreement-label::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #1d8fe8;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.agreement-link {
    color: #1d8fe8;
}
```

```
php

require_once('');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$cameraCount = $_POST['camera-count'];
$archiveCount = $_POST['archive-count'];
$cameraCost = $_POST['camera-cost'];
$workCost = $_POST['archive-cost'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone-number'];
$totalCost = $_POST['total-cost'];

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                             
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mymail@mail.ru';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setFrom('mymail@mail.ru'); 
$mail->addAddress('yourmail@mail.ru');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с калькулятора';
$mail->Body    = '<strong>Количество камер: </strong>' .$cameraCount.'<br><strong>Размер архива: </strong>' .$archiveCount.'<br><strong>Стоимость оборудования: </strong>' .$cameraCost.'<br><strong>Стоимость работ: </strong>' .$workCost.'<br><strong>Почта: </strong>' .$email.'<br><strong>Телефон: </strong>' .$phone.'<br><strong>Итого стоимость: </strong>' .$totalCost;
$mail->AltBody = '';
```

Comment: Т.е. вас ничего не смущает в этой фразе: "_4 Input и 3 output. На почту приходят значения только из полей input_"?

Comment: Во-первых, пометьте, что должно прийти с `input`, а что с `output`. Тут вряд ли кто-то хочет догадываться. Во-вторых, проблема может крыться не только в php-коде, поэтому как минимум еще нужен html и js

Comment: А что за output-поля такие?

Comment: Все добавил. Поля output:  $cameraCost = $_POST['camera-cost']; $workCost = $_POST['archive-cost']; $totalCost = $_POST['total-cost'];

Comment: @u_mulder http://htmlbook.ru/html/output

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков если у вас есть комментарий по этому поводу, буду рад и благодарен его узнать. Я здесь именно по этому поводу. И, собственно, вопрос задан именно по этому.

Comment: @rusgeli html и css код добавил. Поля output: $cameraCost = $_POST['camera-cost']; $workCost = $_POST['archive-cost']; $totalCost = $_POST['total-cost'];

Comment: Есть у меня немного коментария по этому поводу, но он не очень цензурный... если зацензурить то звучит примерно так: нефик пытаться покушать через задний проход, поля для вывода информации а не ввода.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а если с небес на землю спуститься и попробовать человеческим языком объяснить, умник?

Comment: В переводчик вбейте output, а затем input и посмотрите перевод слов

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков перевод слов этих я знаю. И за что каждое поле отвечает. Проблема с PhP. Как добиться отправки данных из полей output? Если это невозможно, то может есть альтернатива?

Comment: Почему невозможно? вполне возможно, js в помощь. но зачем пытаться покушать задницей - мне досихпор не понятно, эти поля предназначены для вывода информации пользователю, а не для ввода в компьютер, для того чтоб человек не мог поменять значения делают либо скрытое поле рядом ```<input type="hidden">``` либо если информацию пользователь должен видеть но не должен менять RO - ```<input type="text" readonly>``` а не пытаются взять инструменты не имеющие отношения ко вводу информации.... и да, с PHP проблемы никакой нет, ему эти значения(из полей output) просто никто не посылает

Comment: @ElJeko, тут проблема не в php, а именно в клиентской части. Я попробовал прогнать ваш вариант, до сервера в принципе не доходят эти поля через `POST`. Более адекватные варианты таковы: создать скрытые `input`, в которые будут заноситься данные с ваших `output` через js, они уже будут спокойно передаваться через `POST`; отправлять через `ajax`, а данные в форму заносить через `FormData`, попутно добавляя результаты с ваших `output`.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарии

Comment: @rusgeli еще вариант упустили, js валидация формы с последующей отправкой, на стадии валидации - можно менять \ добавлять \ удалять данные которые будут отправлены (нет необходимости прибегать к ajax).

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, верно, тоже хороший вариант, заработался, видать, сегодня, упустил очевидное)